# Is removing the reference to an object sufficient to not get memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Let us say that I have a chess-website. People log in and play chess against others, and my Java-program is doing all the calculations. I see only two options on how I would do it:

- Run a new "instance" of the Java-program for every chess-game. Meaning that I essentially write `java chess` in the terminal every time a new chess-game starts.
- Run one instance of the Java-program, but create a new `Board()` with two `Player` whenever a new game is started. But in this case I need to pay attention to memory leaks, since I will never be terminating the Java-program.

I am assuming that the first option is bad. This assumption is not really based on any knowledge, so I could very well be wrong. But for the sake of this post I am going with the second option. If I am wrong let me know.

Going with the second option, I could do something like this every time a new chess-game is started:

```
Player p1 = new Player(white);
Player p2 = new Player(black);
Board b1 = new Board(p1,p2);
startMatch(b1);
```

and when the game is over these three objects are no longer needed and should be removed from the memory. What I have heard is that the Java-garbage-collector collects all objects that are unreachable.

So if I do this:

```
p1 = null;
p2 = null;
b1 = null;
```

I have accomplished the task? If yes, have I done it in a good way or is this incredibly cringe-worthy and disgusting?

Comment: Removing *all* (live) references to an object is sufficient to avoid memory leaks. We don't see what happens inside of `startMatch` (or later) with these objects. If they are stashed away somewhere, they may very well be kept alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sufficient for the values (or instances) to go out of scope (once unreachable they're eligible for garbage collection), there is **no need** to *explicitly* `null` your references (unless the instance(s) containing them will never go out of scope).

Comment: Agree, setting things to `null` that are about to go out of scope anyway is useless clutter. You may want to set them to `null` if you want them collected before the variable goes out of scope (but in that case, you should probably rethink the variable scope).

Comment: How would I make them go out of scope?

Comment: @Thilo They become eligible for collection if you null them, they aren't necessarily collected.

Comment: @Gendarme How are you keeping them in scope? Presumably this is an instance you have in a session? Remove it from the session.

Comment: "aren't necessarily collected". True. There's nothing really you can (or should) do to force the actual collection. Best you can do is unreference things to make them eligible for collection (i.e. tell the JVM that it can clean them up if it feels it needs more memory).